# Is there any lifecycle method which will get called each time when a fragment is opened?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I tried to use `onStart()` but it doesn't invoke with `ViewPager` in some cases, especially when going to fragment from nearest tab on tablayout.

What can be problem?

Is there any other events that invoke explicitly?

Comment: The [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) might also help you.

Answer (score 0):

[`Fragment#onResume()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#onresume) will be called when the fragment is visible to the user and actively running. This is generally tied to Activity.onResume of the containing Activity's lifecycle.